# JQuery Are you Sure + Rails Nav being ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app, and wanted to emulate the `onunload` effect to prompt before leaving changes. While looking around I found out about [Are You Sure?](https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure).

I have it implemented on a form, and it works on page refreshes, but it isn't working on links that leave the page. I'm thinking this is `turbolink` based so I tried running `$('body').attr("data-no-turbolink", "true");` in the `ready` statement, however I'm getting the same effect.

Since this is Rails specific I'm unsure how to truly emulate it via a Fiddle.

I've tried running it globally on both `form` and the id of the form, and both give the above results.
`$('form').areYouSure();`

Is this a turbolinks issue, or a known issue (That I can't find in the Git Issues) about `beforeunload`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also believe this is turbolinks problem. `Turbolinks 5` is not more compatible with `gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '~> 2.1'`, which would solve this issues with the `jquery libraries`.

Discussion about this
https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks/issues/56

The reason is that the event names changed, so that gem is not working anymore.

https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure/blob/master/jquery.are-you-sure.js

If you check the `jquery.are-you-sure.js` you can see that the function inside it is wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` statement, `(function($) { })(jQuery);`

https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure/blob/master/jquery.are-you-sure.js

You can test this by disabling turbolinks on a specific link

https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#disabling-turbolinks-on-specific-links

If you have `Turbolinks < 5` you can solve this issue by installing a gem called `gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '~> 2.1'`, otherwise you need to understand why the jquery code is not executing on page change... You need to change that `$(document).ready()` statement or `(function($) { })(jQuery);` statement in a `$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {});`

Comment: Thanks for this! My resolution came from wrapping the nav div within `<div class="nav-wrapper grey darken-3" div data-turbolinks="false">`

I'm asking an open ended question at this point, but I seem to keep needing to disable Turbolinks (As you mentioned I'm on TL5), more and more. Is there any sort of consistency patch I can do for jQuery or not really?

Comment: @DNorthrup yes. this is an open issue as you can see from the Github post I linked https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks/issues/56

Installing the gem `jquery-turbolinks` does not fix this, in that file you need to change the `$(document).ready` statement in a `$(document).on("turbolinks:load` statement... remember that `(function($) { })(jQuery);` is synonimous of document ready... otherwise just wait that somebody fixes the issue for the get `jquery-turbolinks` thanks a lot